# File cannot browse in android webview

Tags: android, android-webview

I have converted website to android webview application. but when I try to get image from gallery I cannot access files.

this is my codes what I tried

MainActivity

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private WebView myWebView;
    @SuppressLint("SetJavaScriptEnabled")
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        myWebView = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.webView);
        WebSettings webSettings =myWebView.getSettings();
        webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        myWebView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());
        myWebView.loadUrl("URL");

        myWebView.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
        myWebView.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
        webSettings.setAllowFileAccess(true);
        myWebView.getSettings().setAllowContentAccess(true);
        myWebView.getSettings().setAllowFileAccessFromFileURLs(true);

        myWebView.getSettings().setAllowUniversalAccessFromFileURLs(true);

        myWebView.clearCache(true);
        myWebView.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
        myWebView.getSettings().setAllowFileAccess(true);
        myWebView.getSettings().setGeolocationEnabled(true);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        if(myWebView.canGoBack()){
            myWebView.goBack();
        }else{
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }
}
```

Manifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        package="com.example">
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_INTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_INTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_GPS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_ASSISTED_GPS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="label"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
        android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
        android:hardwareAccelerated="true">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Html

```
<input type="file" #image accept="image/*" (change)="handleInputChange($event)" style="display: none;">
```

Does anybody know why I cannot access files? I cannot found any solution to get help. This is another problem related this issue but no-one answer
[related another problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46603821/file-browse-cannot-work-in-android-webview)

Answer (score 2):

```
    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private static final int INPUT_FILE_REQUEST_CODE = 1;
    private static final String TAG = MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();
   // Storage Permissions variables
   private static final int REQUEST_EXTERNAL_STORAGE = 1;
   private static String[] PERMISSIONS_STORAGE = {
        android.Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,
        android.Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,
        android.Manifest.permission.CAMERA
  };
   private WebView webView;
   private WebSettings webSettings;
   private ValueCallback<Uri[]> mUploadMessage;
   private String mCameraPhotoPath = null;
   private long size = 0;

   public static void verifyStoragePermissions(Activity activity) {
    // Check if we have read or write permission
    int writePermission = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(activity, 
    android.Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
    int readPermission = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(activity, 
    android.Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
    int cameraPermission = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(activity, 
    android.Manifest.permission.CAMERA);

    if (writePermission != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED || 
    readPermission != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED || cameraPermission 
    != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        // We don't have permission so prompt the user
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(
                activity,
                PERMISSIONS_STORAGE,
                REQUEST_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
        );
    }
   }

  @Override
  public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) 
  {
    if (requestCode != INPUT_FILE_REQUEST_CODE || mUploadMessage == null) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        return;
    }
    try {
        String file_path = mCameraPhotoPath.replace("file:", "");
        File file = new File(file_path);
        size = file.length();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("Error!", "Error while opening image file" + 
    e.getLocalizedMessage());
    }

    if (data != null || mCameraPhotoPath != null) {
        Integer count = 0; //fix fby https://github.com/nnian
        ClipData images = null;
        try {
            images = data.getClipData();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Error!", e.getLocalizedMessage());
        }

        if (images == null && data != null && data.getDataString() != null) 
      {
            count = data.getDataString().length();
        } else if (images != null) {
            count = images.getItemCount();
        }
        Uri[] results = new Uri[count];
        // Check that the response is a good one
        if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            if (size != 0) {
                // If there is not data, then we may have taken a photo
                if (mCameraPhotoPath != null) {
                    results = new Uri[]{Uri.parse(mCameraPhotoPath)};
                }
            } else if (data.getClipData() == null) {
                results = new Uri[]{Uri.parse(data.getDataString())};
            } else {

                for (int i = 0; i < images.getItemCount(); i++) {
                    results[i] = images.getItemAt(i).getUri();
                }
            }
        }

        mUploadMessage.onReceiveValue(results);
        mUploadMessage = null;
    }
    }

   @Override
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    verifyStoragePermissions(this);

    webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
    webSettings = webView.getSettings();
    webSettings.setAppCacheEnabled(true);
    webSettings.setCacheMode(webSettings.LOAD_CACHE_ELSE_NETWORK);
    webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webSettings.setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
    webSettings.setAllowFileAccess(true);
    webView.setWebViewClient(new PQClient());
    webView.setWebChromeClient(new PQChromeClient());
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
    //if SDK version is greater of 19 then activate hardware acceleration 
   otherwise activate software acceleration
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 19) {
        webView.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_HARDWARE, null);
    } else if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 11 && Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 19) {
        webView.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null);
    }

    webView.loadUrl("https://www.google.com");


    webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {

        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
            ProgressBar progressbar = (ProgressBar) 
    findViewById(R.id.progress_bar);
            progressbar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
    });
}

;

   private File createImageFile() throws IOException {
    // Create an image file name
    String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new 
   Date());
    String imageFileName = "JPEG_" + timeStamp + "_";
    File storageDir = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(
            Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);
    File imageFile = File.createTempFile(
            imageFileName,  /* prefix */
            ".jpg",         /* suffix */
            storageDir      /* directory */
    );
    return imageFile;
    }

    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    // Check if the key event was the Back button and if there's history
    if ((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) && webView.canGoBack()) {
        webView.goBack();
        return true;
    }
    // If it wasn't the Back key or there's no web page history, bubble up 
   to the default
    // system behavior (probably exit the activity)

    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // handle arrow click here
    if (item.getItemId() == android.R.id.home) {
        Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Home.class);
        startActivity(i);
        finish(); // close this activity and return to preview activity (if 
    there is any)
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
    // code here to show dialog


     Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Home.class);
     startActivity(i);
     finish();
     super.onBackPressed();
     }

    public class PQChromeClient extends WebChromeClient {

    // For Android 5.0+
    public boolean onShowFileChooser(WebView view, ValueCallback<Uri[]> 
    filePath, WebChromeClient.FileChooserParams fileChooserParams) {
        // Double check that we don't have any existing callbacks
        if (mUploadMessage != null) {
            mUploadMessage.onReceiveValue(null);
        }
        mUploadMessage = filePath;
        Log.e("FileCooserParams => ", filePath.toString());

        Intent takePictureIntent = new 
        Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        if (takePictureIntent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) 
       {
            // Create the File where the photo should go
            File photoFile = null;
            try {
                photoFile = createImageFile();
                takePictureIntent.putExtra("PhotoPath", mCameraPhotoPath);
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                // Error occurred while creating the File
                Log.e(TAG, "Unable to create Image File", ex);
            }

            // Continue only if the File was successfully created
            if (photoFile != null) {
                mCameraPhotoPath = "file:" + photoFile.getAbsolutePath();
                takePictureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, 
            Uri.fromFile(photoFile));
            } else {
                takePictureIntent = null;
            }
        }

        Intent contentSelectionIntent = new 
        Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
        contentSelectionIntent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
        contentSelectionIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_ALLOW_MULTIPLE, true);
        contentSelectionIntent.setType("image/*");

        Intent[] intentArray;
        if (takePictureIntent != null) {
            intentArray = new Intent[]{takePictureIntent};
        } else {
            intentArray = new Intent[2];
        }

        Intent chooserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CHOOSER);
        chooserIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_INTENT, contentSelectionIntent);
        chooserIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TITLE, "Select Chooser");
        chooserIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_INITIAL_INTENTS, intentArray);
        startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(chooserIntent, "Select 
        Files"), 1);

        return true;

    }
    }

public class PQClient extends WebViewClient {
    ProgressDialog progressDialog;

    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {

        // If url contains mailto link then open Mail Intent
        if (url.contains("mailto:")) {

            // Could be cleverer and use a regex
            //Open links in new browser
            view.getContext().startActivity(
                    new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url)));

            // Here we can open new activity

            return true;

        } else {

            // Stay within this webview and load url
            view.loadUrl(url);
            return true;
        }
       }

    //Show loader on url load
    public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {

        // Then show progress  Dialog
        // in standard case MainActivity.this
        if (progressDialog == null) {
            progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
            progressDialog.setMessage("Loading...");
            progressDialog.hide();
        }
        }

       // Called when all page resources loaded
       public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
        webView.loadUrl("javascript:(function(){ " +
                "document.getElementById('android- 
         app').style.display='none';})()");

        try {
            // Close progressDialog
            if (progressDialog.isShowing()) {
                progressDialog.dismiss();
                progressDialog = null;
            }
        } catch (Exception exception) {
            exception.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
          }

  }
```

web.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<WebView
    android:id="@+id/webview"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true" />

<ProgressBar
    android:id="@+id/progress_bar"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Error setContentView(R.layout.web); , (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progress_bar); and new ProgressDialog(Web_page.this); what should I add to activity_main.xml

Comment: Error "Default"  in onKeyDown method

Comment: i just updated my answer by removing the onleydown function .

Comment: after login, it wont redirect to the page